# How to recognize the char(255) of C++, in python?

Tags: python, c++

I've written a parser in C++, that parses a text and saves the important content in other files.

Since all the possible characters may be present in the parsed text, I needed a specific delimiter for describing the starting and ending points of the various fields.

In C++, I used the delimiter `char(255)`, because I see that for a `UTF-8` text, it corresponds to `FF` in hexadecimal and it isn't associated with any symbol.

Now I'm in trouble when trying to recognize the `char(255)` in the python file, where I've defined the delimiter as `chr(255)` since it does not recognize it as a special character.

In C++, the usage of this character has been used as follows:

```
#define DELIM char(255)
#define FOLDER string(./folder/)
#define FILE FOLDER + "file_in_folder.csv"
...

using namespace std;

fstream f;

string delim_row = string(1, DELIM) + DELIM;
if(!std::filesystem::exists(FOLDER))
   std::filesystem::create_directories(FOLDER);
f.open(FILE, std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out | std::fstream::app);
if (!f){
   f.open(FILE, std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out | std::fstream::trunc);
   f << "1st_field" << DELIM << "2nd_field" << DELIM << "3rd_field" << DELIM << "4th_field" << delim_row;
}
for(auto mv : this->my_vector)
   f << mv.1st_field << DELIM << mv.2nd_field << DELIM << mv.3rd_field << DELIM << mv.4th_field << delim_row;
f.close();
```

Now, instead, in Python 3, I've tried using the following piece of code, that does not break the various fields in a single row and cannot recognize among rows and fields.

```
arr = []
with open(operations + "file_in_folder.csv", "r") as input_f:
    reader = csv.reader(input_f, delimiter=DELIMITER)
    for row in reader:
        arr.append(row)
```

I don't understand whether I'm doing wrong the assumption in the C++ or in the Python code.
Can you help me?

Thanks so much.

Comment: Nothing to do with your problem, but this is a strange piece of code `string delim_row = string(1, DELIM) + DELIM;`, why not the more obvious `string delim_row = string(2, DELIM);`

Comment: `char(255)` is invalid UTF-8. And UTF-8 shares with ASCII a number of dedicated separators, between 0 (NUL) and 32 (space). E.g. 30 (RS, Record Separator).

Comment: Surely the first thing to do is to look at your output file with a decent editor and check it matches your expectations. That way you will know if its the C++ or the Python that is incorrect.

Comment: @MSalters so, how may I define a separator that surely does not belong to the set of characters in the C++ piece of code? By using the 30 (Record Separator)?

Comment: @Carmine: That's ultimately a deep philosophical question: which character is not in the set of characters? But ASCII defined  a whole set of **non-text** characters, and calls them **control** characters instead. Unicode has a more fine-grained notion of [character categories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_character_property#General_Category),  but Unicode class Cc contains all the ASCII control characters.

Comment: If I understand correctly that valid UTF-8 strings are delimited by 255 byte, try `open(..., errors='surrogateescape')` and `DELIMITER='\udcff'`. See the docs for builtin `open()` function.